# I have P & G-- how do I use the Wincrypt API to generate a Diffie-Hellman keypair?

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, diffie-hellman

There's an MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919730.aspx), but I'm not getting very far:

```
p = 139;
g = 5;

CRYPT_DATA_BLOB pblob;
pblob.cbData = sizeof( ULONG );
pblob.pbData = ( LPBYTE ) &p;

CRYPT_DATA_BLOB gblob;
gblob.cbData = sizeof( ULONG );
gblob.pbData = ( LPBYTE ) &g;

HCRYPTKEY hKey;
if ( ::CryptGenKey( m_hCryptoProvider, CALG_DH_SF,
                    CRYPT_PREGEN, &hKey ) )
{
    ::CryptSetKeyParam( hKey, KP_P, ( LPBYTE ) &pblob, 0 );
```

Fails here with `NTE_BAD_DATA`.  I'm using `MS_DEF_DSS_DH_PROV`.   What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that it just doesn't like the very short keys you're using.

I found [the desktop version of that article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381969.aspx) which may help, as it has a full example.

EDIT:

The OP realised from the example that you have to tell CryptGenKey how long the keys are, which you do by setting the top 16-bits of the flags to the number of bits you want to use. If you leave this as 0, you get the default key length. This *is* documented in the **Remarks** section of the device documentation, and with the *dwFlags* parameter in the [desktop documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379941(VS.85).aspx).

For the Diffie-Hellman key-exchange algorithm, the Base provider defaults to 512-bit keys and the Enhanced provider (which is the default) defaults to 1024-bit keys, on Windows XP and later. There doesn't seem to be any documentation for the default lengths on CE.

The code should therefore be:

```
BYTE p[64] = { 139 }; // little-endian, all other bytes set to 0
BYTE g[64] = { 5 };

CRYPT_DATA_BLOB pblob;
pblob.cbData = sizeof( p);
pblob.pbData = p;

CRYPT_DATA_BLOB gblob;
gblob.cbData = sizeof( g );
gblob.pbData = g;

HCRYPTKEY hKey;
if ( ::CryptGenKey( m_hCryptoProvider, CALG_DH_SF,
                    ( 512 << 16 ) | CRYPT_PREGEN, &hKey ) )
{
    ::CryptSetKeyParam( hKey, KP_P, ( LPBYTE ) &pblob, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike-- I found (from your reference) that it was *two* things.  You have to tell CryptGenKey the key length by or'ing the length in bits, left shifted by 16, into the flags parameter (undocumented, of course, you have to read the sample).  *Also*, the key length must be at least 512 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that `KP_P`, `KP_G`, `KP_Q` are for DSS keys (Digital Signature Standard?). For Diffie-Hellman it looks like you're supposed to use `KP_PUB_PARAMS` and pass a `DATA_BLOB` that points to a `DHPUBKEY_VER3` structure.

Note that the article you're pointing to is from the Windows Mobile/Windows CE SDK. It wouldn't be the first time that CE worked differently from the desktop/server.

EDIT: CE does not implement `KP_PUB_PARAMS`. To use this structure on the desktop, see [Diffie-Hellman Version 3 Public Key BLOBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381974(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but the DHPUBKEY_VER3 structure doesn't appear to allow one to specify P & G (just their bit lenghts).

Also, I should have mentioned, I *am* on Windows Mobile, not desktop.

I wonder if I could just find an OpenSSL port? ;)